# Monitor a program's I/O

Tags: monitoring, io

I have a program which spawns several child processes.

I want to know which files this program and its children are creating, deleting, and modifying.

- `inotifywait` can tell me which files are being accessed, but cannot tell me which process is doing it. And I have to know where the files are being created in order to set up the monitor.
- `auditctl` will let me log which processes modify a file, but, again, I have to know where the files are in order to set up logging.
- `lsof` will tell me all of the files, but doesn't seem to be a good solution for real-time tracking.

Is there anything that will let me monitor a program's file manipulation without knowing a priori which files will be manipulated?

Comment: which filesystem(s) the program would be writing to?

Comment: @venkatc: Either ramfs or ext4.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux you can use `strace` to monitor these kind of events:

```
strace -f -p <PID> -e trace=file
```

On Solaris, you can use `dtrace`. Have a look at the DTraceToolkit tool `opensnoop`, which is installed by default on Solaris 11 under `/usr/dtrace/DTT/Bin/opensnoop`.

```
/usr/dtrace/DTT/Bin/opensnoop -p <pid>
```

Comment: It's certainly not the easiest thing to use, akin to [drinking from the fire hose](https://media.giphy.com/media/2duW3YAnHDTiM/giphy.gif), but properly used, you can get a real sense of what's going on underneath the hood.

Answer (score 5):

For Linux: opensnoop from Brendengreg's perf-tools should do the job
https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools

For Solaris Dtrace is there anyways

Comment: As Lambert mentioned, strace is easy to use on linux - but be careful with production use, as it will slowdown application. More info at this blog post http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-05-11/strace-wow-much-syscall.html