# Is there a way to know which files are being created, read or updated by running app?

Tags: command-line, files

I would like to list all files that have been read, created or updated from the app running.

Comment: Do you need this information about a program that is already running, or, instead, is an answer that would help find this information by running a program in a specific way acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is within [Monitor a program's I/O](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240346/31707) with `opensnoop` available on many Unix (and not only Solaris).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any application or tool that will give you all the information you need about a process in one place. But, if you understand `Linux` there are a few things that will make it worthwhile. The first is that everything is a `file`. This is great because you can simply cat files for information. The second is that all information that you need about processes is in `/proc`. If you have a `PID` of a parent process then you can find anything you like about the process from there. I would suggest `man proc`.

Answer (score 0):

Get your process ID (`firefox` for instance, the second `grep` is to hide the `grep` search itself):

```
ps aux | grep firefox | grep -v grep
```

You will get something like:

```
<login>  <pid> .... /path/to/program
```

You can then run `file` on `/proc/pid/fd/*`

```
file /proc/1809/fd/*
```

You will get something like:

```
....
/proc/1809/fd/94:  symbolic link to `/home/pp/.mozilla/firefox/79bmloy7.default/formhistory.sqlite' 
/proc/1809/fd/96:  symbolic link to `/home/pp/.mozilla/firefox/79bmloy7.default/signons.sqlite' 
....
```